# Is there a way to run an OS already installed, in a kvm?

Tags: ubuntu

I have two drives

- Drive 1 has `Ubuntu 15.10` installed
- Drive 2 has `Kali 2016.1` installed

I want to run Kali in a kvm running inside Ubuntu

My question is there a way to do this without formatting my 2nd drive and reinstalling Kali if yes then please tell me how.

Progress till now:
I have installed all required packages and virt-manager
Now i am trying to set it up in a filesystem directory and then mount drive 2 in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**:

on second thought, I just checked that adding `-hda /dev/sdc` just works in `KVM`.

Comment: Virtual box is type 2 hypervisor but I need to achieve the in a type 1 hypervisor like KVM or esxi.

Comment: @SarthakSingh  Please read my edit.

Comment: I will try it tonight

Answer (score 0):

You can use a physical hard disk as a storage medium using libvirt and KVM. If your Kali installation will run in that virtualized environment is not necessarily clear, but worth a try.

Just create a virtual machine, use existing storage, use your disk drive as storage, and see if it boots.

Comment: i tried this but i couldn't figure out how to set my vm to boot from the hard drive without having to format it.

Comment: just add the drive as a storage backend, and then add the correct partition as a disk for your virtual machine. It might still be interesting to get the thing to boot in a new environment though. You could try to copy kernel and initrd from the second drive to the host and use direct kernel boot.